# Copy Pasting data From 2 Different tables into one

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I aim to append the data from "Year2023" directly following the data from "Year2022" within each column, without introducing additional rows. However, my current code appends the data from the last row of the table separately for each column, resulting in an incorrect outcome.

I hope someone can help me to fix the issue.

```
Sub CopyPasteData()
    Dim Sh2022 As Worksheet, Sh2023 As Worksheet, ShQuery As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Columns As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Query2").DataBodyRange
       If .Rows.Count > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Delete
    End With
    
    Set Sh2022 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Year2022")
    Set Sh2023 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Year2023")
    Set ShQuery = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Table")

    Columns = Array("Customer Name", "Activity Type", "timeInterval.duration", "Description", "Platform", "Start Date")

    For i = LBound(Columns) To UBound(Columns)
        ' Copy data from Year2022
        LastRow = ShQuery.Cells(ShQuery.Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sh2022.Range("Table2[" & Columns(i) & "]").Copy
        ShQuery.Cells(LastRow, i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        ' Copy data from Year2023
        LastRow = ShQuery.Cells(ShQuery.Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sh2023.Range("Table3[" & Columns(i) & "]").Copy
        ShQuery.Cells(LastRow, i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the active sheet and the `Data Table` sheet the same?

Comment: No There are Three Different Sheets with three different Tables

Comment: Copying the Data from `Table2` and `Table3` then pasting it into the Table `Query2`

Comment: It looks like you're deleting all rows (but the first) from table `Query2` in the active sheet since you used `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Query2")`. Later you paste values in the `Data Table` sheet since you used `Set ShQuery = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Table")`. If they're not the same then I'm counting 4 sheets and 3 tables. Please clarify.

Comment: You are right though! Mistakenly it is added as `ActiveSheet` But it should not be. So there are three sheets and three tables. `ActiveSheet = ShQuery `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Specific Columns From Tables to a Master Table

[image]

```vb
Sub CopyPasteData()
    
    Const dSheet As String = "Data Table"
    Const dTable As String = "Query2"
    Dim sSheets() As Variant: sSheets = VBA.Array("Year2022", "Year2023")
    Dim sTables() As Variant: sTables = VBA.Array("Table2", "Table3")
    Dim sCols() As Variant: sCols = VBA.Array( _
        "Customer Name", "Activity Type", "timeInterval.duration", _
        "Description", "Platform", "Start Date")
    Dim dCols() As Variant: dCols = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    With wb.Sheets(dSheet).ListObjects(dTable)
        If .ListRows.Count > 0 Then
            If .ShowAutoFilter Then
                If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            End If
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
        .ListRows.Add
        Set drg = .DataBodyRange
    End With

    Dim slo As ListObject, srg As Range, s As Long, c As Long, srCount As Long
    Dim sCount As Long
    
    For s = 0 To UBound(sSheets)
        Set slo = wb.Sheets(sSheets(s)).ListObjects(sTables(s))
        Set srg = slo.DataBodyRange
        If Not srg Is Nothing Then ' data found
            srCount = srg.Rows.Count
            Set drg = drg.Resize(srCount)
            For c = 0 To UBound(sCols)
                drg.Columns(dCols(c)).Value _
                    = srg.Columns(slo.ListColumns(sCols(c)).Index).Value
            Next c
            Set drg = drg.Rows(1).Offset(srCount)
            sCount = sCount + 1 ' count the sheet
        End If
    Next s
    
    MsgBox "Copied data from " & sCount & " sheet" _
         & IIf(sCount = 1, "!", "s."), _
         IIf(sCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation)

End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed a best solution @VBasic2008 thank you. There is one problem I have changed the Order of the Columns to this `Dim dCols() As Variant: dCols = VBA.Array(1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11)` And the columns which are `2,3,4 and rest` has formulas in it. I do not why the code is disturbing them and makes them `#REF!` error. I hope you can help with this one so the formulas won't get effect when data is pasting.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you're trying to achieve, it looks like you're not far. Might simply be a matter of fixing the indexes where you paste. Something like this might get you there.

Note: I removed the deletion of rows in the "Data Table" worksheet as it doesn't seem necessary for your specific task.

```
Sub CopyPasteData()
  Dim Sh2022 As Worksheet, Sh2023 As Worksheet, ShQuery As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim Columns As Variant
  Dim i As Integer

  Set Sh2022 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Year2022")
  Set Sh2023 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Year2023")
  Set ShQuery = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Table")

  Columns = Array("Customer Name", "Activity Type", "timeInterval.duration", "Description", "Platform", "Start Date")

  For i = LBound(Columns) To UBound(Columns)
      ' Copy data from Year2022
      LastRow = ShQuery.Cells(ShQuery.Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Row
      Sh2022.Range("Table2[" & Columns(i) & "]").Copy
      ShQuery.Cells(LastRow + 1, i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

      ' Copy data from Year2023
      Sh2023.Range("Table3[" & Columns(i) & "]").Copy
      ShQuery.Cells(LastRow + 1, i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Next i

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the issue persists when copying data from Table2 and Table3 and pasting appedned it into Table Query2. Currently, it inserts data from the first column, followed by the second column starting from the last row, and similarly, the third column pastes data starting from where the second column's last row ends, and so forth.